# Loading WebAssembly Binaries on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to load a wasm binary on rails, but I'm only having success if the ".js" glue code and the .wasm binary are on the public folder... If I try to access them trough my views, the .js glue code is not able to find the wasm binary. (failed to load wasm binary file at 'wget.wasm')

Do I need to create a specific route to the wasm binary?  I've tried changing the .wasm location on the .js glue code that is generated after my C code is compiled with emscripten, but without success...

Or do I need to add methods to send the binary file in the controller? I tried use the send_file method, but the .wasm file was being download instead of being loaded to the page...

Using firefox page inspector, I observed that when the request is made through my views, the GET results in a status 500 "Internal Server Error", but when I access through the public folder, it results in a status 200 "OK".

The only info about Ruby on Rails and WebAssembly integration that I found was a github repositor specifically in this [commit](https://github.com/yhara/dxopal/tree/ff4bfe3d0da679775bdd96469b540f9e384e67a1),  of a presentation in RubyKaigi 2017 conference "Ruby, Opal and WebAssembly", but I'm not having any progress using it. It seems that a js code is executed in 
[this](https://github.com/yhara/dxopal/blob/ff4bfe3d0da679775bdd96469b540f9e384e67a1/opal/dxopal/sprite/collision_checker.rb)  .rb file to load the wasm binary, but as I said before, I have not obtained any success using it.

Comment: What is the 500 error you're getting? Can you post it in the question?

Comment: I've added the information to the question, it was an error of the HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

If you base64-encode the .wasm file then you can put it directly in the JavaScript like this:

```
Module.wasmBinaryFile = "data:application/wasm;base64,AGFzbQEAAAAByQ/AAWACf38Bf2A...";
```

which solved a similar problem I was having

Comment: wouldn't that increase your file size?

Comment: Surely, there's a performance impact associated with this solution?

Comment: Size: yes, although it will gzip down to the same when being sent over the internet

Comment: Performance: yes, I think you can't benefit from the compilation starting before the download has finished. But it's a lot better than not working at all 